# Create duplicate records based on values in another table (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently I am working on a piece of requirement where I need to create a copy or duplicate a record of a table based on values in another table based on priority.  Below is my source data

PrivilegeTbl

```
+----------+-----------+
| Priority | UserLevel |
+----------+-----------+
|        1 | Admin     |
|        2 | SuperUser |
|        3 | User      |
|        4 | Guest     |
+----------+-----------+
```

UserTbl

```
+----------+-----------+-----------+
| UserName | UserLevel |   Dept    |
+----------+-----------+-----------+
| Alex     | User      | IT        |
| George   | Guest     | Marketing |
| Bob      | Admin     | HR        |
+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

AccessTbl

```
+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| UserName | UserLevel | AccessGrantedOn |
+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| Alex     | User      | 01-Jan-18       |
| Alex     | Admin     | 01-Jan-19       |
| George   | Guest     | 01-Jan-20       |
| Bob      | SuperUser | 01-Jan-17       |
| Bob      | Admin     | 01-Jan-18       |
+----------+-----------+-----------------+
```

Expected Output:

```
+----------+-----------+-----------+
| UserName | UserLevel |   Dept    |
+----------+-----------+-----------+
| Alex     | Admin     | IT        |
| Alex     | User      | IT        |
| George   | Guest     | Marketing |
| Bob      | Admin     | HR        |
+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Here I need to check if a User in UserTbl having additional UserLevel in AccessTbl which is in higher priority as per PrivilegeTbl and create a copy. So in the expected output Alex is having two records. Bob in UserTbl having additional UserLevel in AccessTbl but the priority is lower so expected output contains only one record as is.

Comment: It's not really creating duplicate records, but eliminating some of the duplicates. Having said that, look into joins, common table expressions and row_number. Shouldn't be so difficult to do. If you want a proper answer, please read [ask] and the guidlines in the [sql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: what have you tried so far? what issues you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.UserName, CASE WHEN ap.Priority > up.Priority THEN up.UserLevel ELSE ap.UserLevel END AS UserLevel, u.Dept
FROM AccessTbl a JOIN UserTbl u ON (a.UserName = u.UserName)
    JOIN PrivilegeTbl up ON (u.UserLevel = up.UserLevel)
    JOIN PrivilegeTbl ap ON (a.UserLevel = ap.UserLevel)
    WHERE up.Priority >= ap.Priority
```